# Cannot use monitor plugged into dock with Thinkpad t440p on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: nvidia, 15.04, nvidia-optimus, thinkpad

This question also covers other graphics problems I've been experiencing.

The **Thinkpad t440p** is certified for [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201307-13930/), but appears to have major problems after I upgraded it from *14.10* to *15.04* (*Kubuntu* specifically).  I've gone from minor problems with suspend (*14.10* started having problems when the computer would just power off rather than suspend) to major problems, specifically being unable to connect my two external monitors (one through *Thinkpad Ultra Dock* and one directly to mini-displayport)

Behavior when using nouveau drivers:

- Monitors plugged into the dock are not detected by X. (xrandr will not list them).  Monitor plugged into mini-displayport still works.
- Random 1s freezes occur every few minutes as I type.

Using the binary *nvidia* drivers (**346**) are far worse, better GL performance notwithstanding.  In addition to also having the before mentioned problems, the computer will boot up at times with very small icons (seems the DPI is calculated wrong?) and resumes from suspend can cause graphical corruption/sheering that requires reboot.

The final option is disabling the nvidia card with the binary nvidia drivers and using only *Intel*.  If I boot up the computer when docked, the external monitor plugged into dock is detected. But there is no plug-and-play support - if I eject the running computer and then plug in back in - I still cannot use the monitor.

Has anyone had these issues with the **t440p** before and solved them?

lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06) 
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06) 
00:01.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x8 Controller (rev 06) 
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06) 
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06) 
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 04) 
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04) 
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family KT Controller (rev 04) 
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-LM (rev 04) 
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 04) 
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04) 
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d4) 
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev d4) 
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 04) 
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation QM87 Express LPC Controller (rev 04) 
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04) 
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04) 
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208M [GeForce GT 730M] (rev a1) 
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5227 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01) 
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 83)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it appears no one knows (nor have bug reports on ubuntu been followed up with).  I'm downgrading to Kubuntu 14.10. There appear to be serious problems in Ubuntu 15.04 around plug-and-play monitor support and I'd advise others to avoid installing it.